# json_decode is returning string instead of array/object if the original content is from external server

Tags: php, json, decode

I need to fetch a JSON content from an external site, but for some strange reason I can't make it an array or object, instead json_decode is returning it as string. If I copy the same original content in full length into a variable and use that instead then it works correctly: json_decode turns it into object/array.

```
function isJson($string) {
    json_decode($string);
    return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}

$url = "http://www.igetthestufffromhere.com";

$response = trim(strip_tags(file_get_contents($url)));
```

I have tried without trim and strip_tags and also  tried with CURL and the result is the same.

```
//$response ="[{\"SaleDate\":\"2015-10-22T14:09:00\",\"End\":\"2015-11-22T00:00:00\",...SHORTENED A LOT..\"ChildList\":null}],\"ExName\":\"SELVÄ\",\"SomeName\":\"\"}]";

echo "ENCODING:".mb_detect_encoding($response); returns: utf-8 every time

if( isJson($response) ){
    echo "Yes it is JSON"; // This is TRUE in both cases (local variable and fetched).
}

$json = json_decode($response, true);

var_dump($json);
```

var_dump returns: string(302087) ""[{\"SaleDate\"....]"" when I get the response from that other domain, but when I use the local variable with exactly same manually copy-pasted content it returns: array(139) { [0]=> array(34) { ["SaleDate ...

Edit: I don't understand why I just got a downvote, I have tried to solve this for about 5 hours, I pasted all the code needed to answer and there is a real problem here.. so what's the matter with my question!? I shouldn't have this problem?! My first question in this site too.

Comment: It looks like `$response` is a double encoded JSON string. If you actually have backslashes in your JSON, that's a bad sign.

Comment: Ok thank you for sharing your though. So why is it double encoded in the file_get_contents-version and not in the copy pasted and how do I fix this? I can not change the original text.

Comment: If you paste the string `"[{\"SaleDate\"...}]"` into PHP as `$json = "[{\"SaleDate\"...}]"`, the meaning changes because it's interpreted as a PHP string literal. To preserve the value accurately, it must be `$json = '"[{\\"SaleDate\\"...}]"'`. Have you taken that into account…?

Comment: You `json_decode` it twice. Or, preferably, you get the server to return sane JSON in the first place.

Comment: Ok @deceze I added single quotes around that variable: `code  //$response = ' "[{\"SaleDat ` like so. And after that I get the same behaviour from the variable too, it won't be decoded into JSON object/array but a string. SO I assume I have to remove one quotes around the fetched response? If yes then how?

Comment: Uhm, no, again: decode it twice. `json_decode(json_decode($string))`.

Comment: Ok thank you @deceze it works now. One more question: will this work when I need to fetch json from other sites, or will this double decoding now f-up other json content? And if it does, is there a way to detect it?

Comment: I am thinking of first doing it once, then: `code if( is_string( $response ) ){ do it again } `

Comment: Well, yes, it *will* eff up *proper* JSON. Again, the preferred solution here would be to get the server fixed, if that's possible at all. And yes, something like `while (is_string($response)) $response = json_decode($response)` would do.

Comment: Oh that WHILE is genious and it works. Thank you a lot! I also added a counter to it so that after 4 iterations it stops trying.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem was answered by @deceze

It was because the JSON was double-decoded. So it needed to be double-encoded. Here is the working code:

```
function isJson($string) {
    json_decode($string);
    return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}

$url = "http://www.igetthestufffromhere.com";

$response = trim(strip_tags(file_get_contents($url))); 
$i=0;
while (is_string($response)){ //if is still string
    $response = json_decode($response); // decode to object
    if( $i>3 ){  // stop if still not working
        break 1;
    }
    $i++;
}

var_dump($json); // is always JSON object
```